# Django-cms menu template tag issue

Tags: django, menu, django-templates, django-cms

HI im totally stuck with this one at the moment and i really hope someone can help me out with this problem.

I have a django / django-cms build that contains a lot of pages.  the site is divided up in to 4 main sections, lets say these sections are grand parents.  each grand parent can have a number of children, which in turn can have any number of children so we have a grandparent, parents and children realtionship going on.

basically i have the nav for each grandparent being display which shows all of the parent and children for that section like so:

`{% show_menu_below_id request.current_page.reverse_id %}`

the problem i have is as i navigate the menu obviously starts changing to show the items below that pages id.  I only want to ever show the menu for grandparent sections not the other pages as i navigate through the site

i have 3 templates one for the grandparents one for the parents and one for the children. I hope this is clear enough to explain my problem. just to re-iterate no matter how far i go down through the sub menu i need to only the menu as if i was at the top level of the section IE the grad parent page

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood what you want. Are the "grandparent" pages at the root? If so, I think this should do the trick:

```
{% show_menu 1 %}
```

It displays the navigation from the first level (level 0 is the root- or "grandparent"-level). The [docs](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/navigation.html#show-menu)  go into more details on how to use the `show_menu` tag (it's not exactly intuitive...)

Comment: Jesus i tried everything but that yesterday :D thanks so much, its definately a step closer however still not totally what i need. i need the tree to be fully exapnded for each section (the grabndparent) no matter how far down i go for that relationship.  so if i hit the about section (grandparent) which has the parents what we do (parent) and our work (parent) i need the children to show for each parent, currently it will only display the children under the active parent page - does that make sense.. Is this possible using the menu tag or will it need something custom. again thanks!

Comment: The `extra_inactive` argument could possibly help. Have you tried `{% show_menu 1 100 100 100 %}`?

Comment: yeah i tried that already that would be perfect if it didnt exapnd the entire tree for the whole site, if i specify the second param it displays the grandparents of the other sections too.. :( its a shame but its obv something a bit to specific for the tag!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the whole thing expanded, then on the relevant pages you could get a bit cheeky and use CSS to hide the lower levels that you wanted hidden.

There are enough classes and stuff being applied by default that you could probably target the relevant areas.

Obviously it's not ideal, but it's probably about as close as I could get.